# How does Devextreme DataGrid compare with Ag-Grid for react

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, ag-grid, devextreme

What are your thoughts on DevExtreme vs Ag-Grid for React?

Performance wise, I find both are similar.
I find DevExtreme easier to use.

Would like to know recent experiences.

Answer (score 3):

Disclosure: I work for [ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-getting-started/) as Lead Frameworks Developer

I can't comment on DevExtreme as I'm not familiar with it, but here are my (biased) thoughts on ag-Grid:

- The documentation is a living thing. We don't consider any feature complete until there is a working example of it included in the documentation
- We're constantly innovating and ensuring our framework support is ahead of actual framework support. In the case of React we had Portal support available before React 16 (as a beta)
- ag-Grid's feature list is extensive - I doubt you'll find a grid with more features out there, especially considering we offer support across multiple frameworks too
- ag-Grid (both the free and the enterprise version) are open source

As I say I'm obviously biased, but hopefully this is helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for a succinct response. FYI, I believe you meant to write, "Disclosure:" rather than "Disclaimer:"

Comment: Indeed :-) Corrected